# How to animate fractal flames?

Tags: drawing, fractals

I'm currently writing the fractal flames algorithm from [FLAM3](http://flam3.com/flame_draves.pdf).

However the paper does not describe how animations are created. In section 9, Motion Blur: states something like blur can be achieved by varying the parameters. I'm currently using random parameter generation, so the next frame doesnot even look like the first frame, what is the algorithm for smooth blending/animating?